# PIC12F simulator: Why isn't the oscillator running?

Tags: pic, oscillator, timer

I have written firmware for a PIC12LF1572 that I am testing in the MPLAB X simulator.  The program runs and correctly responds to stimuli, except when it needs to wait for a timer interrupt.

After a bit of debugging, it seems that the timer is not counting *at all*.  That is, TMR1 does not increment.  I have set the timer clock to the low-frequency internal oscillator (LFINTOSC), which runs at 31kHz.  It appears that LFINTOSC is not running; furthermore, examining the oscillator status (OSCSTAT) register shows that *no* oscillators are running!  This can't be right, as the program is definitely running.  Furthermore, the watchdog timer is enabled, ensuring that LFINTOSC will not be shut off.

[image: No oscillators running]

Does the simulator accurately simulate the oscillators and use them to drive execution?  If not, then how do I get my timers to run in the simulator?  Or, is this a case of pilot error?  The code that configures the timer is as follows:

```
// Set up the timer and its interrupt
T1CONbits.TMR1CS = 3; // LFINTOSC @ 31kHz
T1CON |= 0x08; // Turn on timer's oscillator; pin not named by the library (!?)
PIR1bits.TMR1IF = 0;
PIE1bits.TMR1IE = 1;
INTCONbits.PEIE = 1;
ei();

// Interrupt in 1/10 second (31kHz clock).
TMR1 = -3100;
T1CONbits.TMR1ON = 1;
```

Comment: What version of MPLAB are you using? On my version (admittedly a 'few' months out of date) that PIC is marked as having only partial simulator support (yellow blocks next to Simulator in the project properties).

Comment: Oops, sorry, good question.  I'm using the latest (at the time of this writing) version, 2.35.  How do you view what is and isn't supported, like you're saying?

Comment: I figured out how to view what peripherals are supported for a given device.  In the MPLAB X "Dashboard" there is a section under Debug Tool called Click for Simulated Peripherals.  Clicking it will do what it says on the tin.  The simulator supports Timer 1 and the oscillators for my part.  I'm not sure what is wrong.